# Coda Slider Tab Navigation

Tags: modal-dialog, coda, coda-slider, csb

I am using Coda-Slider for my website and I want to know if there is a way to change the content of each tab. For example, the user navigates onto tab2 where I placed a link to redirect the user to another page. Is there a way NOT to navigate away from the page nor the tab but instead load the link inside the tab? I was thinking it would look something like a modal box that would stay inside the tab instead of popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see 1[9. Coda-Slider Sliding Tabs](http://blogger.techflaps.com/2009/05/56-css-tabs-navigation-menu-scripts-and.html) or you might want to try [35. JQuery IDTabs if you want the effect to be non-intrusive](http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/#advanced)